# Как правильно написать слово: выходит или выходят?

Tags: орфография, грамматика, глаголы, единственное-множественное-число, множественное-число

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой из вариантов правильный (если можно, объясните почему):
"Всё больше людей выходИт на улицУ"
"Всё больше людей выходЯт на улицУ"
"Всё больше людей выходИт на улицЫ"
"Всё больше людей выходЯт на улицЫ"

Answer (score 1):

**Все варианты корректны**. Смотря что Вы хотите сказать.

Выйти на улиц**у** - выйти за пределы жилого дома, наружу.

Выйти на улиц**ы** - пройти по улицам города, часто  с протестом, но в устной речи возможно использовать множественное число и в значении "выйти из домов на улицы".

Теперь о согласовании подлежащего, выраженного количественно-именным сочетанием со словами много, мало, немного, немало, сколько, столько, несколько и другими,  со сказуемым в числе:

> **Основной нормой является
>   использование сказуемого в единственном числе**. Для постановки
>   сказуемого во множественное число необходимо действие дополнительных
>   факторов. Например, наиболее распространённой является форма
>   множественного числа сказуемого при подлежащем, указывающем на
>   одушевлённые предметы, прежде всего – на людей.

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/41-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_russkii_yazyk_i_kultura_obscheniya/stages/783-33_nekotorye_osobennosti_soglasovaniya.html

У нас как раз указание на людей, значит, возможно множественное число, но и единственное будет нормой.

Так что если Вы имеете в виду, что люди нарушают режим самоизоляции, то корректны будут предложения *Всё больше людей выходИт на улицУ. Всё больше людей выходЯт на улицУ*

Если Вы хотите сказать о протестах, то *Всё больше людей выходИт на улицЫ. Всё больше людей выходЯт на улицЫ*.